# Error al consumir API desde mi proyecto ( c# )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, localhost, webapi

que tal?? Tengo tres proyectos en mi solución, uno la biblioteca de clases con los repositorios, otro el MVC, y un tercero que es una API.
Mi intención es resolver ciertas funcionalidades de la aplicación web consumiendo esta API que les nombraba. Por postman todo es hermosoo response 200ok y todo bárbaro, ahora, a la hora de utilizar el código me quedo por el camino...

Lo que realmente no sé es si esto sucede debido a que tengo todo dentro del mismo servidor localhost ( y para inicializar el mvc la APi no queda corriendo como proyecto de inicio ), o si es el codigo el que falla. Según muestra Mr. BreakPoint la información llega desde el formulario al parametro, y luego el flujo del programa va hacia  [ var result = tareaPost.Result; ], allí explota 404 :>( .

Les comparto el código.
**CONTROLLER**

```
public class PostulanteController : Controller
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    Uri registerUri = new Uri("http://localhost:50310/api/RegisterPostulante");

    public PostulanteController()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50310");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));}

    // POST: api/Postulante/CrearPostulante
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CrearPostulante(VMPostulante postulante)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var doPost = client.PostAsJsonAsync(registerUri, postulante);

            var result = doPost.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                TempData["ResultadoOperacion"] = new string[] { "alert-success", "Postulante creado correctamente." };
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            TempData["ResultadoOperacion"] = new string[] { "alert-danger", "Algo ha fallado." };
            return View(postulante);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["ResultadoOperacion"] = new string[] { "", "" };

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
```

**CODIGO DE LA WEBAPI**

```
public class PostulanteController : ApiController
{
    RepoPostulante rp = new RepoPostulante();
    RepoUsuario ru = new RepoUsuario();

    //POST: <server>/api/RegisterPostulante/{p}
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult RegisterPostulante([FromBody] VMPostulanteAPI p)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Postulante pAux = rp.findByCi(p.cedula);

            Postulante pAux = rp.findByCi(p.cedula);

            if (pAux == null)
            {
                if (rp.add(VMPostulanteAPI.ConvertToPostulante(p)) && ru.add(new Usuario() {cedula = p.cedula, clave = p.clave}))
                {
                    return Ok();
                }
                else return InternalServerError();
            }
        }
        else return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que url usas desde postman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución a mi problema. La API y los métodos estaban bien, la gran estupidez de mi parte fue querer consumir la api desde el puerto localhost de mi proyecto MVC :D. Se ve que me dormí en la parte de la clase que explicaban que los dos proyectos se inicializan en puertos distintos, muy fuerte jejeje... Casi me cuesta un trabajo de estudios.

Para los que estan en la misma situación... Click derecho sobre el proyecto API en la solución --> Propiedades --> pestaña Web, y allí tendrán el puerto localHost donde esta alojada su API ( que va a ser distinto al puerto donde estará el MVC o proyecto q fuese ) . Saludos